# Android. How to show 2 items in recycler view and then add one item on every button click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to show 2 items by default and add items in recycler view when we click button in main activity. Those item contains edittext so I have to get the data from edittext in my main activity.

Comment: show what you have got for now and where is your exact problem. SO isn't for posting requests for code snippets, nor for asking such basic questions (read doc and some tutorials, plenty of them)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create two different ViewType/Layouts to implement this.

Sharing related links below..

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-viewtype-in-android/

[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types)

Answer (score 0):

For adding items to Recycler view when you click in a button you should add the item in the list and notify adapter that new item added at the end of the recyclerview using `notifyItemInserted()`
and for the other question for getting the edittext value from the adapter to the activity you can create a callback interface that implemented in the activity and pass the reference to the adapter and fire it from adapter when Edittext value is changed